Forzar carga de scripts y CSS
Hola tengo un problema con mis navegadores, Opera Browser y MS Edge, el problema es que hay veces que le cuesta muchísimo recargar las modificaciones que hago en los scripts o en los CSS, pese a pulsar CTRL + F5. ¿Hay alguna solución para evitar esta tardanza en la recarga?

Comprueba si tienes algun sistema de cache en tu servidor web, tipo nginx, y si es así, renueva su cache y vuelve a probar.

Intenta con F12->Aplicación->Almacenamiento->botón "borrar datos del sitio" https://i.sstatic.net/A21N69G8.png

Hola Sergio, puede que te sea de ayuda las respuesta a esta pregunta Eliminar caché automáticamente

@Marcos no creo que se una buena opcion eliminar el cache siempre, dado que esto fuerza al navegador a  volver a cargar todo nuevamente, lo recomendable seria agregar a tu css version en caso de estar aprendiendo te recomiendo hacer esto al final de tu css ?v=1 o el numero que deses ejemplo index.css?v=1 esto le indica a los navegadores que es una nueva ruta y version por lo que vuelven a solicitarlo y aplicar los cambios

@Bryro, estoy 100% de acuerdo con lo que planteas y es una forma que he utilizado más de vez en algunos desarrollos. Pero acá el OP no especifica qué es lo que busca, ni el stack con el que trabaja, por lo que la solución que se ofrece en esa otra pregunta es una opción viable (no necesariamente la mejor). Ya que estamos otra forma es utilizar ETag

Pero hablamos de los cambios en desarrollo o de los cambio al usuario final ya en la aplicación real??

Hablamos de que modifico el archivo js con VSCode lo guardo y no se cargan los cambios que realizo con lo que no puedo ver el resultado de ese cambio.

Pues prueba con Control + boton de recarga de la página de la barra de navegación de tu navegador, y si no chuta con Shift + el mismo botón

Ya he CTRL + F5  y SHIFT + F5 y nada

Bueno, no decia F5, sino el icono que aparece en la barra de navegación, a la izquierda de la URL
